# Getting sprockets error when using jekyll-assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed a tutorial here to add Jekyll to my rails app:

http://www.sitepoint.com/jekyll-rails/

Everything was working great until I attempted to link sprockets up with the Jekyll assets. The sprockets asset pipeline actually seems to be working for the blog part of my site (localhost.com/blog) when now when I got to simply http://localhost.com I get the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `jekyll' for #):

This started when I followed the sprockets portion of the tutorial which went like this:

```
add gem 'jekyll-assets'
```

alter config/jekyll.yml to contain :

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-assets
assets:
    dirname: assets # _assets
    baseurl: /blog/assets/
    sources: # asset subdirectories
        - _assets/stylesheets
        - _assets/javascripts
        - _assets/images
    cachebust: hard
    js_compressor: uglifier # included by rails
    css_compressor: sass # included by rails
```

Move blog assets around:

```
$ cd blog
$ mkdir _assets
$ mkdir _assets/stylesheets
$ mkdir _assets/javascripts
$ mkdir _assets/images

# move around assets
$ mv _sass/* _assets/stylesheets/ && rmdir _sass
$ mv css/* _assets/stylesheets/ && rmdir css
```

Add to _includes/head.html:

```
{% stylesheet main %}
```

Anyone know what could be the cause of the error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `jekyll' for #):?

It's occurring when processing <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> in my application.html.erb file.